# Passing customdata to Operating system option of azure vmss - Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-vm-scale-set

While we create `Virtual machine scale set` in `azure` , there is an option for passing the `Custom data` under `Operating System` like below
[image]

How can i pass the script there using `terraform` , there is an option [`custom data`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.html#custom_data) which seems to be used for newly created machines from `terraform`, but the script is not getting stored there. How do i fill this with the script i have using `terraform`. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you suggesting you want to pass custom_data after provisioning?

Comment: i dont get you @ChristianPearce , can you please ask again

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html#custom_data

Comment: Is your question suggesting the custom_data field is not working in terraform Be cause it is not showing up in the Custom Data field in the portal?  can you post your example code?

Comment: no, actually, `custom data` field in the portal is saved for all the servers coming under the `vmss` , but the `custom data` using terraform is applying straight to the servers, instead of storing it here is what my question is.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/custom-data), the custom_data can only be passed to the Azure VM at **provisioning time**.

> Custom data is only made available to the VM during first boot/initial
> setup, we call this 'provisioning'. Provisioning is the process where
> VM Create parameters (for example, hostname, username, password,
> certificates, custom data, keys etc.) are made available to the VM and
> a provisioning agent processes them, such as the Linux Agent and
> cloud-init.

The scripts are saved differed from the OS.

### Windows

Custom data is placed in `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\AzureData\CustomData.bin` as a binary file, but it is not processed.

### Linux

Custom data is passed to the VM via the `ovf-env.xml` file, which is copied to the `/var/lib/waagent` directory during provisioning. Newer versions of the Microsoft Azure Linux Agent will also copy the base64-encoded data to `/var/lib/waagent/CustomData` as well for convenience.

To upload custom_data from your local path to your Azure VM with terraform, you can use [filebase64](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/filebase64.html) Function.

For example, there is a test.sh script or cloud-init.txt file under the path where your `main.tf`or `terraform.exe` file exists.

```
 custom_data = filebase64("${path.module}/test.sh")
```

If you are looking for executing scripts after VMSS created, you could look at the [custom extension](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine_scale_set_extension.html) and [this sample](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/examples/vm-scale-set/linux/extensions/main.tf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i think my question is not clear, in the `vmss` portal, there is a place to save the `customdata` for future servers that might come up during scaling, i wanted to save the `customdata` for those